# Blend a video and a still image

Tags: python, opencv, video, blending

I want to blend a video captured using camera and a still image, tutorials provide the code that works for two still images how to go about with a video (frame) and a still image?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read the how to ask section.  Note that questions asking for tutorials tend to be frowned upon.  Also note that you need to clarify a bit even if you can get it to be an on-topic question. What you're looking for might be what is frequently called green screen (or color compositing), but it might also just be overlaying.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the issue is solved

Answer (score 1):

The issue was perhaps the size of two, here now img1 is video captured through webcam, and img2 is the still image

```
def add_two_images(img1,img2):
    """Blends two images to one with different weights given to each"""
    height, width, depth = img1.shape  ## Needed when img1 is a jpeg image
    img2 = cv2.resize(img2,(width, height))
    #print (img1.size, img2.shape)
    dst = cv2.addWeighted(img1, 0.5, img2, 0.5, 0)
    cv2.imshow('dst', dst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't explain what you mean by "blending". I'm assuming that you're trying to overlay an image on **every** frame of a video. To do so, you can use the addWeighted() method in a loop for every frame in the video, as shown:

```
img=cv2.imread("still_image.jpg");
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True: 

    ret,vid=cap.read()
    result=cv2.addWeighted(img,0.5,vid,0.5,0)
    cv2.imshow('overlay', result)
    video.write(img)
    if(cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('b')):
            break
```

Comment: what i mean is you used variable vid in function addWeighted yet has not been set,

Comment: made the change. Thanks for the heads-up